# How do I prevent Wirecast from crashing?

Tags: streaming, software, live, mac, obs

I'm attempt to livestream from a 2016 MacBook Pro, but for some reason Wirecast (12.2.1) crashes. It doesn't matter what I'm doing, it only stays open for a couple of minutes, then it just completely closes.

Comment: Don't use wirecast in the first place. I've always had trouble. I like vmix.

Comment: @DigiVisionMedia it’s for macOS?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought vmix had a mac version.

Comment: Can you use https://obsproject.com/ instead? It does a lot of what Wirecast does

Comment: This question is really a wirecast support forum question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external monitor, try unplugging it and loading up Wirecast.  Some people have reported too much video resources being in use cause problems.

Comment: I didn’t, though it may have something to do with discrete graphics being enabled as well